# HTTP request of Locust and Jmeter varies load on tomcat server

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, locust

I tried 500 users with 100 Ramp up/Hatch rate per seconds. The load generated was monitored for tomcat using JConsole.

For same set of request JMeter requests were using 100-80% CPU usage where as locust was around 60-30% CPU usage.

I wanted to get the bottle-neck for the server how many maximum request it can server.
Can i simulate same using locust I tried setting min-max-wait to 0 but no use.

I tried 1000 concurrent users in locust but the RPS was same. Using Jmeter i was able to find that the RPS more that this is supported by my server. RPS value by locust gives 160 where as JMeter gives 250 which is huge difference.

Locust can't generate load on my tomcat server.

Can any one please help me to explain what i am missing to simulate the load similar to JMeter.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How did you setup min_wait  and max_wait values?

Comment: class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = WebsiteTasks
    min_wait = 10
    max_wait = 100

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Locust Issue # 464](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/464) my expectation is that Locust doesn't consider so called ["embedded resources"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses), to wit images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. which actually generate lots of extra asynchronous requests and produce the main load.

Check what exact requests are being sent by Locust and JMeter using either [Tomcat access log](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) or a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) - the requests should be the same in terms of amount/nature. Ideally they also should match the requests which are being sent by real user using real browser.

Comment: Thanks, I am testing angular application, which does not loads the resources when we send HTTP request, Also the same happens with JMeter its also not loading embedded resources. I actually send requests of images and js

Answer (score 0):

Follow @aldenpeterson-wf   [suggestion](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/646) of setting min_wait and max_wait with 1000 ms to get rate per second

> Have you looked at min and max wait? Setting them to both be 1000 (ms) would result in locust making 1 request/sec per client which seems to be exactly what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks, I checked this before writing here, When I send request its not sending with the speed at which Jmeter is sending, That is causing the server to use 100% CPU and huge RAM consumption. This I was not able to see with Locust using that much resources and the RPS due to which is less. I don't want to set some limits to sending, I want to send maximum request My server can support.